# Syntax error in MySQL while importing Excel file #1166 - Incorrect column name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload an Excel file into a MySQL database. I get a syntax error from MySQL while importing Excel file #1166 - Incorrect column name ...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `myfarmer`.`ville` 
(    
     ` Évosges ` VARCHAR( 42 ) ,
     `1230` INT( 5 ) ,
     `45.958333` DECIMAL( 8, 6 ) ,
     `5.5` VARCHAR( 17 )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: possible cause can be spaces in ` Évosges ` column

Answer (score 0):

You can't have spaces at the start of your column names:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table foo (` bar ` int);
ERROR 1166 (42000): Incorrect column name ' bar '
MariaDB [test]> create table foo (`bar` int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

So

```
` Évosges ` VARCHAR( 42 ) ,
```

should be

```
`Évosges` VARCHAR( 42 ) ,
```

Comment: Nope thats not it, look at the statement, he's definitely confusing create table and insert

Comment: i can remove spaces what the same above error was occur again ...Know what can i do..?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO here my friend...

CREATE TABLE creates a storage space with a definite structure while INSERT INTO inserts data into the table.

Your two statements should look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myfarmer.cities (
    name VARCHAR(42), 
    something INT(5), 
    longitude DECIMAL(8,6), 
    lontitude DECIMAL(8,6), 
    somethingelse VARCHAR(17)
);
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO myfarmer.cities VALUES('Évosges', 1230, 45.958333, 72.25122, 5.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), "Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters.". Also, I would remove the starting space from `Évosges`, since it seems wrong.